# Oracle Forms - How can I automatically tab to next field after the user inputs 10 characters?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm trying to make a form where one of its fields will automatically tab to the next one after the user inputs ten characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this for each text fields, which you want to give that functionality, individually by setting `Data` -> `Maximum Length` property to `10`, and `Functional` -> `Automatic Skip` property to `Yes` from the property palettes of them.